# Escaping filename suffix in a regex?

Tags: regex, filenames

I'm trying to match a variable length string followed by the filetype suffix in an XML filename using a regex:

```
varrrrrriableLengthString.xml
```

Currently I'm using this regex with a greedy match, the second backslash is to escape the first, which is to escape the dot.

```
[A-Za-z0-9]+\\.[xX][mM][lL]
```

I've tested this on [RegExr](http://www.regexr.com/), and it matches with only one backslash. However my CPP parser requires the double backslash.

***How can I properly escape the filename suffix?***

Comment: You need two backslashes if you put the regex in a string literal, e.g. `string pattern = "[A-Za-z0-9]+\\.[xX][mM][lL]"`, because you need to escape backslashes in string literals. Your code will only see one backslash however - you can see this by printing it: `cout << pattern << endl;`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also escape chars using the `[]` notation, in your case `[.]`. The main advantage is that there is no *"one or two backslashes?"* question anymore, and I find it more readable IMHO.

It just does not work with brackets, i.e. to escape a `[` (or `]`), you still have to use `\[` (or `\\[` for a string literal) <strike>and not `[[]`</strike>.

Backslashes still have to be escaped using another backslash too.

Comment: Ah! now that seems obvious!